# Select values from same column from same table

Tags: sql-server

I've a column Question_Id from which I've to derive two sets of values based on a different column in SQL Server 2008.

Question_id and  ID

- 243        73
- 244        73
- 245        73
- 429        192
- 430        192
- 431        192

How can I get them like this: (This is only for temporary table)

- 1   243        429
- 2   243        430
- 3   243        431

Thanks a lot in advance.
Manish

---

Thanks for your replies. 
For those who weren't clear about the question - I want the result to be like that temporary table. Yesterday I realized that, Actually its not possible to select different values from same column.... I used two temporary tables 
`SELECT QUESTION_ID WHERE ID = 73 INTO #TEMP1` and `SELECT QUESTION_ID WHERE ID = 192 INTO #TEMP2`. Then I inner-joined both tables to use the data for some INSERT operation... Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand how you got those results...

Comment: Please expand on the question -- what do the three columns in the second "temporary table" represent, and how are you generating them by hand?

Comment: Guys — he's relying on the natural order to take the "first" 73 value and pair it up with the "first" 192 value, then the second 192 value, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  There is no natural ordering in SQL databases, so without the 1, 2, 3 values in the original rows, there's no way to pair up, for instance, 243 and 429.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a cross join with something like:

`SELECT t1.qid, t2.qid FROM table as t1, table as t2 WHERE t1.qid=243 AND t2.qid between 429 AND 431;`

And insert that into a new table with an AI index, you could create something like your description.

Comment: but it seems like a very odd order. you may want to reconsider what you are really trying to accomplish.